# Renewcommands \dots* from amsmath

Tags: amsmath, ellipsis

According to Zaitcev, V.; Janishewsky, A.; Berdnikov, A. (1999), *Russian Typographical Traditions in Mathematical Literature*. EuroTeX'99 Proceedings
the dots between integrals should be `\ldots`:

[image]

This publication is available [here](http://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf).

I want to use the semantically oriented `\dots*` commands from amsmath and adjust them to the requested conventions.

My naive attempt was to copy the line from `amsmath.sty`

```
\newcommand{\dotsi}{\!\@cdots}
```

and change the definition of `\dotsi` with renewcommand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\dotsi}{\!\@ldots}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \int \dotsi \int dx_1 \dotsm dx_N
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However, this returns following error:

```
You can't use `\spacefactor' in display math mode \@->\spacefactor  \@m {} \int \dotsi
```

What would be the correct way to do this for `\dotsi` and also for the other `\dots*` commands?

Comment: `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\dotsi}{\!\@ldots}\makeatother` -- `@` needs `\makeatletter` outside of package or class files. This kind of error pops up in questions basically every day here (or even more than once a day ;-) ... No comment on the rules of Russian math typography here, however

Comment: Ahhhh. Sorry, I always forget about this. Grummel grummel. ( I would really like to have more sensible error messages in tex.)

Comment: For an explanation of `makeatletter`  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do. If someone has some motivation why Russian math typography is not advisable in this circumstance, I would love to here about this as well.

Comment: @Hotschke If you want to implement and use Russian typography, follow those rules; the standard AMS style is tailored to American typography.